# Delphi search for files in a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010, findfirst

Got this pretty straight forward function to search for files:

```
function FindFiles(const Path, Mask: string; IncludeSubDir: boolean): integer;
var
  FindResult: integer;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FindResult := FindFirst(Path + Mask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, SearchRec);
  while FindResult = 0 do
  begin
    //!!!!!!!! This must synchronize Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(Path + SearchRec.Name);
    Result := Result + 1;
    FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
  if not IncludeSubDir then
    Exit;
  FindResult := FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, SearchRec);
  while FindResult = 0 do
  begin
    if (SearchRec.Name <> '.') and (SearchRec.Name <> '..') then
      Result := Result + FindFiles(Path + SearchRec.Name + '\', Mask, True);
      FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
end;
```

It is called with :

```
FindFiles('C:\','*.*',TRUE)
```

How to break this into Delphi thread?
This code suits my needs (d2010) I just need to put it (or parts of it) into a thread.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TFileSearcher = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FPath, FMask: string;
    FIncludeSubDir: boolean;
    FItems: TStrings;
    function FindFiles: integer;
    procedure UpdateTheMemo;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; const Path, Mask: string; IncludeSubDir: boolean);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

uses Unit1;

{ TFileSearcher }

constructor TFileSearcher.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; const Path, Mask: string;
  IncludeSubDir: boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FPath := Path;
  FMask := Mask;
  FIncludeSubDir := IncludeSubDir;
end;

procedure TFileSearcher.Execute;
begin
  FItems := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FindFiles;
    Synchronize(UpdateTheMemo);
  finally
    FItems.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFileSearcher.UpdateTheMemo;
begin
  Form1.Memo2.Lines.Assign(FItems);
end;

function TFileSearcher.FindFiles: integer;
var
  FindResult: integer;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  ThisPath: string;
begin
  ThisPath := FPath;
  Result := 0;
  FindResult := FindFirst(FPath + FMask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, SearchRec);
  while FindResult = 0 do
  begin
    FItems.Add(FPath + SearchRec.Name);
    Result := Result + 1;
    FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
  if not FIncludeSubDir then
    Exit;
  FindResult := FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(ThisPath) + '*.*', faDirectory, SearchRec);
  while FindResult = 0 do
  begin
    if (SearchRec.Name <> '.') and (SearchRec.Name <> '..') then
    begin
      FPath := IncludeTrailingBackslash(ThisPath + SearchRec.Name);
      FIncludeSubDir := true;
      Result := Result + FindFiles();
    end;
    FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
end;

end.
```

If you want the items to be added to the VCL control one-by-one you lose some of the benefits of threading, but sure, it can be done:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TFileSearcher = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FPath, FMask: string;
    FIncludeSubDir: boolean;
    FItemToAdd: string;
    function FindFiles: integer;
    procedure UpdateTheMemo;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; const Path, Mask: string; IncludeSubDir: boolean);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

uses Unit1;

{ TFileSearcher }


constructor TFileSearcher.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean; const Path, Mask: string;
  IncludeSubDir: boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FPath := Path;
  FMask := Mask;
  FIncludeSubDir := IncludeSubDir;
end;

procedure TFileSearcher.Execute;
begin
  FindFiles;
end;

procedure TFileSearcher.UpdateTheMemo;
begin
  Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(FItemToAdd);
end;

function TFileSearcher.FindFiles: integer;
var
  FindResult: integer;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  ThisPath: string;
begin
  ThisPath := FPath;
  Result := 0;
  FindResult := FindFirst(FPath + FMask, faAnyFile and not faDirectory, SearchRec);
  while FindResult = 0 do
  begin
    FItemToAdd := FPath + SearchRec.Name;
    Synchronize(UpdateTheMemo);
    Result := Result + 1;
    FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
  if not FIncludeSubDir then
    Exit;
  FindResult := FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(ThisPath) + '*.*', faDirectory, SearchRec);
  while FindResult = 0 do
  begin
    if (SearchRec.Name <> '.') and (SearchRec.Name <> '..') then
    begin
      FPath := IncludeTrailingBackslash(ThisPath + SearchRec.Name);
      FIncludeSubDir := true;
      Result := Result + FindFiles();
    end;
    FindResult := FindNext(SearchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @Rawn: I fixed a bug a minute ago. Did you try the new version?

Comment: It updates the memo only at the end of the search. It looks like it needs to be synchronized somewhere in the middle of the FindFiles function. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

An OmniThreadLibrary-based solution which uses messages instead of Synchronize can be found [here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2008/11/background-file-scanning-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer [Indy 10 IdTCPClient Reading Data using a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554142/indy-10-idtcpclient-reading-data-using-a-separate-thread/555820#555820) and the link contained in it for a more elegant way of running a given function inside a thread using anonymous methods. The idea is to implement once a class that executes any `TProc` inside a thread. The anonymous method feature then lets you easily define this `TProc`in-place and with access to all local variables of the calling context.